# How to iterate a sequence of integers in decreasing order?

Tags: ballerina

I'd like to iterate a sequence of integers in decreasing order but I find no built-in way to do that. I'm doing this in the context of array indexes but the concept is of course general.

Ballerina has a [range expression](https://ballerina.io/spec/lang/2022R2/#section_6.26) but that can be used only to iterate incrementally:

> The result of a range-expr is a new object belonging to the object
> type Iterable<int,()> that will iterate over a sequence of integers in
> increasing order [...]

So this works as expected:

```
public function main() {
    final string[] x = ["A","B","C","D"];

    foreach int i in 0 ..< x.length() {
        io:print(x[i]);
    }
    io:println();
}
// prints: ABCD
```

But the following doesn't (i.e. it prints nothing) as `x.length()-1` is greater than `0` (it compiles without problems though):

```
public function main() {
    final string[] x = ["A","B","C","D"];

    foreach int i in x.length()-1 ... 0 {
        io:print(x[i]);
    }
    io:println();
}
```

My current workround is to generate the indexes and consume them in two different steps, e.g.:

```
public function main() {
    final string[] x = ["A","B","C","D"];

    final int[] indexes = from int i in 0 ..< x.length() order by i descending select i;
    foreach int i in indexes {
        io:print(x[i]);
    }
    io:println();
}
// prints: DCBA
```

But this feels clumsy compared to range expression. We also loose the (supposed) laziness of the range expression, right?

The documentation says the return type of range expression is:

> a new object belonging to the object type `Iterable<int,()>`

This and the documentation about [Iterable](https://ballerina.io/spec/lang/2022R2/#section_5.7.2) hints that one might implement such an object but I fail to see how.

Or is there any other ways to iterate range/sequence of integers in decreasing order?

I'm using:

```
$ bal version
Ballerina 2201.1.0 (Swan Lake Update 1)
Language specification 2022R2
Update Tool 1.3.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, there's no direct way to achieve this. But it's in the plans. There's an [spec issue](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/775) to track this.

As an alternative, you can write an iterator (an implementation of [object:Iterable](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.object/0.0.0/objectTypes/Iterable) interface). But it may look like a lengthy approach. Following example decrements from 20 to 10.

```
import ballerina/io;

public class Decrementor {
    private int startVal;
    private int endVal;
    private int i;

    public function init(int startVal, int endVal) {
        self.startVal = startVal;
        self.endVal = endVal;
        self.i = startVal;
    }

    public function next() returns record {|int value;|}? {
        if self.i < self.endVal {
            return ();
        }

        int val = self.i;
        self.i -= 1;
        return {value: val};
    }
}

class Iterator {
    *object:Iterable;

    public function iterator() returns Decrementor {
        return new Decrementor(20, 10);
    }
}

public function main() {
    foreach any|error i in new Iterator() {
        io:println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I adapted this answer and created a helper functions that return either incrementing or decrementing iterators: https://lib.ballerina.io/janihur/intutil/latest

Answer (score 1):

```
import ballerina/io;
public function main() {
    final string[] x = ["A","B","C","D"];

    // Method 1
    foreach string i in x.reverse() {
        io:println(i); // DCBA
    } 
    io:println(x); // ["A","B","C","D"]
    
    // Method 2
    foreach int i in -(x.length()-1) ... 0 {
        io:println(x[-i]); // DCBA
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not asking how to reverse an array (Method 1). The array indexes are just examples of integer sequences to give some usage context. I'm asking how to create/iterate sequence of integers in decreasing order. Method 2 introduces a nice trick to fool the incrementing range expression! It's a "tricky" code I normally don't like but here we're working around the language limitation so an up-vote is appropriate.